# Database design for e-commerce product variants with laravel

Tags: laravel, database, e-commerce

I am developing an e-commerce store so i want to create a multi-product variants with multi prices

so basically till now i have 5 tables:

SQL Table

So my idea is to make all products as variant product till if the product had just one color and one price

but the problem how to connect the attributes to the product_variants table

for example i have T-Shirt product i want to assign (Color, Size) Attribute to the product_variants table In Attribute_values table we have the values (red, L, XL)

so in the end the product variants should be like this:

```
1. T-shirt Red, L = 40$
2. T-shirt Red, XL = 50$
```

So can i have some help with database structure: because i think i need 2 more table

table to assign attributes to product variants
table to assign attribute product variants to attribute values.
also i feel there is problem with product_variants table because how can i know which product_variant for(red xl)

Thanks for all

Need design helps me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because you still have the price column in the attribute_sku pivot table. It should be on the skus table instead. Otherwise you have nowhere to put the price if a product doesn’t have any attributes.

You also need to pay attention to naming, as you have typos, and randomly abbreviating words (“desc”) when there’s no need to. Just call the column description. That’s what it is.

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->text('description')->nullable();
});
```

```
Schema::create('attributes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
    $table->string('name');
});
```

```
Schema::create('skus', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('sku')->comment('The actual alpha-numeric SKU code');
    $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
    $table->char('currency_code', 3);
    $table->unsignedInteger('unit_amount');
});
```

```
Schema::create('attribute_sku', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->primary(['attribute_id', 'sku_id']);
    $table->foreignId('attribute_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
    $table->foreignId('sku_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
    $table->string('value')->comment('The value for this SKU and attribute combination, i.e. Small, Red, etc.');
});
```

Obviously add any other columns you may need.